# Concatenating date functions mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

A mysql query is returning unexpected. I'm trying to concatenate a few strings containing date queries like so:

```
mysql> select month(timestamp) +'-'+ day(timestamp) + '-' + 
       year(timestamp) as date FROM table ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1;
```

and I'm getting a 4 digit result, which I assume is the sum of the expected result:

```
+------+
| date |
+------+
| 2035 |
+------+
```

I've also tried casting each one as `CHAR` which didn't work:

```
mysql> select CAST(month(timestamp) as CHAR) +'-'+ CAST(day(timestamp) as CHAR) + '-' + 
CAST(year(timestamp) as CHAR) as date FROM table ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Could someone let me know what I'm doing wrong? ... and I guess how to fix it would be nice too :)

Comment: `+` is the [addition operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_plus) (but works in MSSQL for string concatenation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MySQL, use `CONCAT_WS`

```
CONCAT_WS('-', month(timestamp),day(timestamp),year(timestamp))
```

query,

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', month(timestamp),day(timestamp),year(timestamp)) AS DATE
FROM   tablename
ORDER  BY timestamp DESC 
LIMIT  1
```

or use `DATE_FORMAT`

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%m-%d-%Y') AS DATE
FROM   Table1
ORDER  BY timestamp DESC 
LIMIT  1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e9fd/4)

Other(s):

- [DATE_Format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)
- [CONCAT_WS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

Comment: awesome! plain old `CONCAT` worked perfectly. forgot about those ... thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using CONCAT, DAY, MONTH, YEAR, etc to format dates is silly.

If `timestamp` is an integer column containing a UNIX timestamp use this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`), '%m-%d-%Y') AS `Formatted Date`
...
```

If `timestamp` is a date/datetime column use this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%m-%d-%Y') AS `Formatted Date`
...
```